# How to create laravel string prefix auto incrementing primay key auto insertable in data table?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I would like to create a custom primary key with a fixed string as prefix and then auto incremented integer value added with string and it should be auto insert able in table as primary key like $table->id() in migration file.

my id should be for example like std-1000 and it should be auto incremented and inserted automatically in the data table.

How can i write code for this? Can anyone pls help me?

Answer (score 1):

in migration:

```
$table->string('id')->primary();
```

in model:

```
public function getIncrementing(): bool
{
    return false;
}

public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->id = 'std_' . ($model::count() + 1);
    });
}
```

And also need to use SoftDeletes for still save count.